# CSS float:right

Tags: css

I am attempting to position two elements in opposite directions. I came across something that seemed to do what I wanted, but I can't seem to float the div to the right.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

In the following, I was expecting *section-title* to be on the left and *feeds* to be on the right...

http://jsfiddle.net/n3Dvg/

Tia!
S.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Dvg/7/ 

put a width to #section ( i used 400px because of workspace )

and then I removed the float:left; adding a display: inline-block attribute from #section .section-title, #section .feeds

hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi now define  **css** uner `id content`

as like this

```
#content #section .feeds{
float:right;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n3Dvg/1/)***

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your styling. Write **#section .feeds** after **#section .section-title, #section .feeds** to override your style.

For example Write like this:

```
#section .section-title, #section .feeds {
 float:left;
            }
            #section .feeds {
                float: right;
                text-transform: none;
            }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/n3Dvg/8/

Answer (score 0):

You have a `float: left` in `section .section-title, #section .feeds` which is conflicting.

Either change that or add `!important` after the `float: right`.

Answer (score 0):

just add `!important` after `float:right`

```
#section .feeds {
float: right !important;  // to override any conflict 
text-transform: none;
}
```